# How do I make the following subquery in Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

For example, using the Tinkerpop's toy graph data (graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()), I want to do something like the following:

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').has('name', 'marko').project('a', 'b').by().by(...)
```

I want to use a property of the vertices from the first traversal and use that in the query inside second by().

Something like this pseudocode:

```
by(__.V().has(hasLabel('person').has('name', [property-from-first-traversal])))
```

This might be easier to do in separate queries, but I want to do it in one query - something like a Subquery in SQL.

Comment: can you clarify what the value of `[property-from-first-traversal]` is expected to be? is it something other than "marko"? perhaps you could expand your example a bit to make it more clear?

Comment: @stephenmallette In the example, the `[property-from-first-traversal]` can be any property from the vertice that was the result from the first query. And in the 2nd `by` I want to query vertices with properties that has the value of `[property-from-first-traversal]` and project those vertices. Please let me know if that's not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('name','marko')
==>v[13]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name', 'marko').
           project('a', 'b').
             by().
             by(__.as('x').V().hasLabel('person').where(eq('x')).by('name').count())
==>[a:v[1],b:2]
==>[a:v[13],b:2]
```

However, be careful with `where()` filters, thus far no provider (that I am aware of) will turn this into an index lookup, hence it will be a scan over all `person` vertices in your graph.

Comment: Thanks, your query is similar to what I wanted but not exactly. It helped me get to this query which is almost what I want: `g.V().has('person','name', 'marko').project('a', 'b').by().by(__.values('name').as('x').V().hasLabel('person').values('name').where(eq('x')))
==>[a:v[1],b:marko]` except, do you how I can query `b` in my query by `name` like I did but project it as the vertex instead of the string `marko`?

Comment: You're close. Your second `by()` should look like this: `.by(__.as('x').V().hasLabel('person').where(eq('x')).by('name'))`.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Also good call on the index concern. I will be adding a search index on my equivalent  `Person` vertex in my DSE.